# `pip install` gives FileNotFoundError regarding METADATA

Tags: python, pip

I recently downloaded a package via pip and although the package was downloaded successfully, I got a glaring error message that I can't seem to find the solution to. Here's the full traceback-

```
Requirement already satisfied: torch in ./anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from toma) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in ./anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from toma) (5.7.0)
ERROR: Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3021, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2815, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3012, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2815, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 517, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 114, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 53, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2736, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3023, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3014, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1420, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(path)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1616, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jmespath-0.9.5.dist-info/METADATA'
```

I've taken a look at the GitHub Issues like [this one](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5681) or [this one](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6647), but the solutions don't work for me.

Has anyone seen this error occur before? If so, how might I be able to solve it? Thanks.

**Update**

Just for some extra information for future users, zealous's answer is mostly correct but I had to make some additional steps:

I had two folders starting with `jmespath`: `jmespath-0.9.4.dist-info` and `jmespath-0.9.5.dist-info`. The 9.5 one only had a `metadata.json`, but the 9.4 one had a `METADATA` file. I copied the `METADATA` file into `9.5`. This led me to another similar error regarding folders `boto3-1.12.12.dist-info` and `boto3-1.12.30.dist-info`. Same deal, simply copy `METADATA` from the lower version into the higher version.

I have no idea what these things entail though, so if anybody would be able to shed some light on that that'd be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the folder by following the path

```
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/userconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jmespath-0.9.5.dist-info
```

You will find that there is no metadata file. there will other folder `0.9.5.dist-info` which will have your metadata file. Just move it outside into the above directory. It should work.